# Showing items using Angular2 ng-bootstrap NgbPagination

Tags: pagination, angular2-template, ng-bootstrap

I want to show a list of items using Angular2 ng-bootstrap   NgbPagination in my angular application.  Each page has 6 items(3 in top and 3 in the bottom).

Anyone, please give an example for showing items using this ng-bootstrap   NgbPagination

Comment: All the documentation you need are on https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/pagination     including links to plunker examples

Comment: how to display items in pagination